# Programming text identification questions

Tags: discussion, questions, question-quality

I can’t find any information on whether about books fit on SO or not. Not so much *recommend a book to learn…* questions, but rather questions about specific books.

There seem to be a small handful of questions bout things like whether something in a book was correct or not, and a some closed questions about recommendations, but what about book-identification questions?

For example, I am trying to find a book on BASIC that I read as a child and recall pretty much everything except the title. I don’t know if I can ask that on SO (or for that matter, anywhere else).

Comment: (Hmm, I can’t find a good tag to use for Meta questions on question relevancy/validity/belonging/fit/etc. Maybe later I’ll consult a thesaurus to check if any such tags exist.)

Comment: There you go ;)

Comment: you should have taken a free shot and integrated that question into this one. "For instance, can I ask *the name of the book about BASIC by Ziggy Wainwrite from about 1986 with the blue cover* or would that be OT?"

Comment: Actually, I had considered it (I did mention BASIC), but that would definitely not have fit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are asking about anything pretty much anything other than a *specific* programming problem that you need *help* to *debug* or *find an alternative solution to*, it is off-topic.

In your example, you are asking for help finding a book.  That still qualifies as *finding a favorite off-site resource*.  Now, I imagine you would argue that it's not opinion based. Well...

1. It is not likely to be useful for other users. Just imagine trying to make a searchable title.
2. It's hard to be sure that it's the book you want. This will probably lead to lots of recommendations.

So, short answer:
**No, you shouldn't ask about that here.**

---

Depending on the question, you may be able to get help on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), but read the help center very carefully first.

Or, if you find a suitable chat room, you could ask there to see if anyone happens to know.

Comment: Alternatively, he could make an attempt to ask about this book in one of the chat rooms.

Comment: True, I forgot about that.

Comment: Thanks for the link to Soft-rec, I haven’t been keeping track of new sites, and that one is definitely a good one to know.

Comment: @Cupcake, actually, I already checked the chat rooms but could not find any sort of general-discussion room for some reason.